# Phonegap / Cordova: Uint8ClampedArray and Canvas.imageData.data.set

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, canvas, cordova

I'm currently writing a image editor using HTML and Javascript. I tried to port it to mobile using Cordova / Phonegap. Depending on which device I use (Emulator / SE Xperia Mini Pro) I get two different errors.

## For the emulator I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Uint8ClampedArray is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/editor.js:26

The part of the code where I use the Array looks like this:

```
Editor.prototype.save = function(){
    eD.history.push(new Uint8ClampedArray(cD.imageData.data)); //eD.history is an Array
};
```

I'm using this method to copy the whole array and not just getting a reference to it. If I only do something like

```
eD.history.push(cD.imageData)
```

I have the problem that the values in this array are changed as well.

## For the device I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'set' at file:///android_asset/www/js/editor.js:35

I'm trying to set the imageData of my canvas back to what I have stored in eD.history:

```
Editor.prototype.undo = function(){
    if(eD.history.length > 0){
        cD.imageData.data.set(eD.history.pop()); //cD is my canvas
    }
    this.draw();
};
```

Those bits work fine on my computer (and over Ripple), but they wont work if I use them from within Cordova / Phonegap.

Since I'm just learning how to use this framework I'm wondering if this is because Phonegap doesn't support those features yet?

Thanks